# How do I override navbar color in the ASP.NET site generated by VS2013?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web

I have some experience with HTML and CSS, but these VS2013 generated sites include lots of stuff - bootstrap, modernizr, etc. I'm completely lost. Any advice how to change the navbar background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013's MVC 5 templates use twitter bootstrap for css styling. To customize twitter bootstrap in your MVC application, go to the [twitter bootstrap download page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and enter in the color values that you desire, then replace the twitter bootstrap files in your project with the one you customized and downloaded.